# CFL Ballast Calculate Primary Turns

Tags: flyback, diy, ballast

There are online designs that use a simple ferrite bolt 50 turn primary and 500 turn seccondary powering one 5 watt CFL. I attempt to customize it with:

Specs: [TDK Core](https://pccomponents.com/datasheets/TDK-E141.PDF)

[image: schematic]

([source](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=20%20watt%2C%205%20watt%20Fluorescent%20Lamp%20Inverter%20Circuit&t=hk&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fmakingcircuits.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2Fcfl.png))

- Vin primary= **6V DC**
- Core material **PC40**
- Saturation at **380 mT**

  CFL:
- Power output **5,5 Watt**
- Nominal voltage = **34V**
- Current nominal = **0.18A**
- Breakdown voltage: Unknown

Transistors: Arbitrary

Question 1:
Is just taking half of the values, so 26 turns primary and 260 turn seccondary adequate or bad practice for my **PC40** material core? Or propper approximation? Is your calculus more efficient?

Because my two seperate calculations innitially yielded 4 and 5 turns for primary.
I thought this can't be right. And the variables have to be estimated guessed,
and I'm pretty bad at that.

Question 2:
Can you come up with a better more efficient design by calculus?
Or is 4 or 5 turns primary pretty close to optimal here or should I go with 26?, or YOUR value?
Can your calculus yield a more efficient N1/N2 for the given specs?

I know that primary inductance leakage plays much less of a role in cfls than in other circuits, but:

Question 3:
Is it the primary inductance leakage which causes the voltage spike on the secondary when the load circuit side opens by a glow starter, or even without a starter, when it's normally closed?
Or what inductance specifially cause the voltage spike to overcome breakdown voltage?

Thanks for taking a look at this community!
I believe together we can solve many electrical problems!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _"estimated guessed"_ That won't work. You need to know your switch frequency, max on-time at max input voltage and core area to get started. Calculate according to Vt=NAB. Also, please show your schematic.

Comment: Thank  you winny for editing the messy original post! duty cycle =40%. The Ae is 51,8mm², and I strongly suspect core is overkill for a 5,5W load capable of max. 70W forward mode? And that could be one reason why I get 4 or 5 turns prim. with the formulas, because of very high cross Area of 51,8²? with a very low inductance primary 0,604uH, secondary 43,671uH. The Fsw (switching freq.) I chose to be 300khz, but it's purely copycatted, edmucautiously guesstimated. I might as well choose 25khz and by chance get more turns? Though I did put 300khz into the fromula as exampled in the guide.

Comment: Hello winny, thank you for your answer. Here is how I got the 5 turns, t=Vout/2/(Ae in m²)/300khz/0.38T;          
t=6V/2/0.00000518m²/300khz/0.38T;                                                          
t= 5,08 I chose maxiumum field 2x because of a flyback transfomer. What is incorrect here winny? I chose 300khz because I have to guess a freuency, I have no ide at what freuency a flyback like this would swing at. I'd like to hear your professional advice if you want to help me. I will try to give you a schematic to have a look at, since you want one, but I don't know how it works here.

Comment: Hello winny, I added the rquested schematic of you to the original post. Here again: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=20+watt%2C+5+watt+Fluorescent+Lamp+Inverter+Circuit&t=hk&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fmakingcircuits.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2Fcfl.png